# angular material close mdDialog from template directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm tring to close dialog by this manner :

```
showAlert(ev) {
    this.mdDialog.show({
      restrict: 'E',
      template:'<loader></loader>' +
      '    <md-button ng-click="this.mdDialog.hide()" class="md-primary">' +
    '      Close Dialog' +
    '    </md-button>' ,
      parent: angular.element(document.body.childNodes[5]),
      clickOutsideToClose:true
  });
};
closeDialog() {
  this.mdDialog.hide();
};
```

but the button appears and do nothing. 
Any idea ?

Comment: Any special reason for why you are not using $mdDialog instead of this.mdDialog? You can inject $mdDialog in your own directive without problems...

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't matter..

Comment: Any chance of puting your code in a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found  the answer there
http://webiks.com/mddialog-with-a-confirmation-dialog/ ,

in the last plunker in page https://embed.plnkr.co/HiLJlsp0yfcukxi2McNZ/ .

the scope property was not needed.

P.S

Now I see @camden_kid answer after edition was, correct for me as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ALjNPZ?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" class="md-padding" ng-cloak="" ng-app="app">
   <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.show($event)">Open</md-button>
  </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  this.show = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      restrict: 'E',
      template:'<loader></loader>' +
      '    <md-button ng-click="vm.hide()" class="md-primary">' +
    '      Close Dialog' +
    '    </md-button>' ,
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      controller: DialogController,
      controllerAs: "vm"
    });
  };
});

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  this.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
}
```

Comment: Is there a `this.` correpondent to this solution? I once read on John Papa's guideline to avoid using `$scope`

Comment: it's didn't worked to me. I also tried to bring $scope to constructor and then to save it in this.myscope=$scope, and still no error appears except than Wanrning :
<md-backdrop> may not work properly in a scrolled, static-positioned parent container.